# Working immediately with instances of asynchronous (dynamically loaded) classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, asynchronous, methods, placeholder

The situation was that I wanted to create an instance of a helper class, but that helper class required initialisation through external scripts, so it was inherently asynchronous. With

```
var obj = new myObj();
```

clearly an call to

```
obj.myMethod();
```

would yield undefined, as obj would either be empty or undefined until its methods and params were loaded by the external script.

Yes, one could restructure things to have a callback pattern and work with the new object within that, but it gets cumbersome and awkward when working with a large and varied API with many dynamic objects as I've been working with.

My question has been, is there any possible way to cleverly get around this?

Comment: Why would you have an object load its methods asynchronously? What does that even mean? You have constructor function and then load some other file that defines its prototype after instantiating it?

Comment: In my case, the problem is you have a large library of classes and you only want to load what you need. This allows things to be loaded as they are used. But I can imagine other reasons, for example if you have some class that needs to load a new framework before it starts running its logic.

Comment: In that case you are looking for AMD implementation like [http://requirejs.org/](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: I've looked at it a bit, admit I haven't poured myself in to all its possibilities, but a bit restrictive don't you think? Doesn't it make you keep all your code inside callbacks on its require calls in the header? Kind of nice to have the freedom to just open up a fresh page and initialise new objects anywhere you like, any time you like, without having to keep track of what you're using up top....

Comment: Cheers for reminding me that this stuff is called AMD btw.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the academically trained programmers out there have a name for this sort of approach, but I put it here in case it's not better written somewhere.

What I've done is modify my loader class to use a placeholder+queue system to instantly return workable objects.

Here are the components. Sorry that there are jQuery bits mixed in, you can easily make this a pure-JS script but I've got it loaded anyway and I'm lazy.

'Client' makes this request, where 'caller' is my handler class:

```
var obj = caller.use('myObj',args);
```

In Caller, we have

```
Caller.prototype.use = function(objname,args) {
    var _this = this;
    var methods = ['method1','method2'];
    var id = someRandomString();
    this.myASyncLoader(objname,function(){
        var q = [];
        if (_this.objs[id].loadqueue) {
            q = _this.objs[id].loadqueue;
        }
        _this.objs[id] = new myRemotelyLoadedClass(args);
        //realise all our placeholder stuff is now gone, we kept the queue in 'q'
        _this.objs[id].isloaded = true;
        //once again, the jquery is unnecessary, sorry
        $.each(q,function(a,b){
            _this.objs[id][b['f']](b['a']);
        });       
    });
    _this.objs[id] = _this.createPlaceholderObj(methods,id);
    return _this.objs[id];
}
```

This function basically initiates the loader function, and when that's done loads a new instance of the desired class. But in the meantime it immediately returns something, a placeholder object that we're going to load with all of our remotely loaded object's methods. In this example we have to explicitly declare them in an array which is a bit cumbersome but liveable, though I'm sure you can think of a better way to do it for your own purposes.

You see we're keeping both the temporary object and future object in a class-global array 'objs', associated with a random key.

Here's the createPlaceholderObj method:

```
Caller.prototype.createPlaceholderObj = function(methods,id) {
var _this = this;
var n = {};
n.tempid = id;
n.isloaded = false;
$.each(methods,function(a,methodCalled){
        n[methodCalled] = function(){
        _this.queueCall(id,methodCalled,arguments);
    }
});
return n;
 }
```

Here we're just loading up the new obj with the required methods, also storing the ID, which is important. We assign to the new methods a third function, queueCall, to which we pass the method called and any arguments it was sent with. Here's that method:

```
Caller.prototype.queueCall = function(id,methodName,args) {
if (this.objs[id].isloaded == true) {
    this.objs[id][methodName](args);
} else {
    if (this.objs[id].loadqueue) {
        this.objs[id].loadqueue.push({'f':methodName,'a':args});    
    } else {
        var arr = [{'f':methodName,'a':args}];
        this.objs[id].loadqueue = arr;
    }
}
}
```

This method will be called each time the client script is calling a method of our new object instance, whether its logic has actually been loaded or not. The IF statement here checks which is the case (isloaded is set to true in the caller method as soon as the async function is done). If the object is not loaded, the methodName and arguments are added to a queue array as a property of our placeholder. If it is loaded, then we can simply execute the method.

Back in the caller method, that last unexplained bit is where we check to see if there is a queue, and if there is, loop through it and execute the stored method names and arguments.

And that's it! Now I can do:

```
var obj = caller.use('myObj',args);
obj.someMethod('cool');
obj.anotherMethod('beans');
```

and while there might be a slight delay before those methods actually get executed, they'll run without complaint!

Not too short a solution, but if you're working on a big project you can just put this in one place and it will pay many dividends.

I'm hoping for some follow-ups to this question. I wonder, for example, how some of you would do this using a deferred-promise pattern? Or if there are any other ways? Or if anyone knows what this technique is called? Input from JS whizzes much appreciated.